Error: exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: permission denied for Logstash container on Podman
I am trying to run the podman container for Logstash on Podman.
My command is like:
podman run \
--detach \
--name lgs01 \
--net els-net \
--publish 5000:5000 \
--publish 5044:5044 \
--publish 9600:9600 \
-it \
--volume /appbase/logstash/config/:/usr/share/logstash/config/ \
--volume lgs01data:/usr/share/logstash/data \
--volume certs:/usr/share/logstash/certs \
docker.xxx.com/logstash/logstash:8.11.4

My logstash.yml on mount:
api.http.host: 0.0.0.0
config.reload.automatic: true
pipeline.separate_logs: true
config.reload.automatic: true
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://es01:9200"]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: "logstash_system"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: "xxx"

After running the container and checking the logs, I get this error:
exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: permission denied


I was suspecting that bind mount folder was somehow corrupt. But I deleted the official Logstash image and pulled it again. Then it worked as a magic.
